# Nodes do not find each other OrientDB Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, orientdb, hazelcast, minikube

I am trying to build an OrientDB cluster which consists of 3 nodes with Kubernetes (in Minikube). I am using StatefulSet with all the cluster configurations mounted as volumes.
The problem is when I check all the pods' logs it looks like each pod creates its own cluster instead of joining a single cluster.
What could be the cause of it?

Hazelcast.xml config looks like this:

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.3.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.discovery.enabled">true</property>
  </properties>
  <network>
    <join>
      <!-- deactivate normal discovery -->
      <multicast enabled="false"/>
      <tcp-ip enabled="false"/>
      <!-- activate the Kubernetes plugin -->
      <discovery-strategies>
        <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
                            class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
          <properties>
            <property name="service-dns">orientdbservice.default.svc.cluster.local</property>
            <property name="service-dns-timeout">10</property>
          </properties>
        </discovery-strategy>
      </discovery-strategies>
    </join>
  </network>
</hazelcast>
```

I am using service dns name as one of the approaches to use Hazelcast plugin with Kubernetes.

default-distributed-db-config.json file:

```
{
    "autoDeploy": true,
    "hotAlignment": false, 
    "executionMode": "undefined",
    "readQuorum": 1,
    "writeQuorum": "majority",
    "readYourWrites": true,
    "newNodeStrategy": "static",
    "servers": {
        "*": "master"
    },
    "clusters":{
        "internal": {
        },
        "index": {
    },
        "*": { 
      "servers" : [ "<NEW_NODE" ] 
    } 
    }
}
```

Listeners part from orientdb-server-config.xml:

```
<listeners>
    <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
    <listener protocol="http" socket="default" port-range="2480-2490" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
        <commands>
            <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg GET|*.json GET|*.woff GET|*.woff2 GET|*.ttf GET|*.svgz" stateful="false">
                <parameters>
                    <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                    <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                </parameters>
            </command>
        </commands>
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="utf-8" name="network.http.charset"/>
            <parameter value="true" name="network.http.jsonResponseError"/>
            <parameter value="Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*;Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" name="network.http.additionalResponseHeaders"/>
        </parameters>
    </listener>
</listeners>
```

StatefulSet I have defined:

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: orientdbservice
spec:
  serviceName: orientdbservice
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: orientdb
      type: container-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: orientdb
        type: container-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: orientdbservice
        image: orientdb:2.2.36
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c", "cp /configs/* /orientdb/config/ ; /orientdb/bin/server.sh -Ddistributed=true" ]
        env:
        - name: ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: orientdb-password
              key: password.txt
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2424
          name: port-binary
        - containerPort: 2480
          name: port-http
        - containerPort: 5701
          name: hazelcast
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /orientdb/config
        - name: orientdb-config-backups
          mountPath: /configs/backups.json
          subPath: backups.json
        - name: orientdb-config-events
          mountPath: /configs/events.json
          subPath: events.json
        - name: orientdb-config-distributed
          mountPath: /configs/default-distributed-db-config.json
          subPath: default-distributed-db-config.json
        - name: orientdb-config-hazelcast
          mountPath: /configs/hazelcast.xml
          subPath: hazelcast.xml
        - name: orientdb-config-server
          mountPath: /configs/orientdb-server-config.xml
          subPath: orientdb-server-config.xml
        - name: orientdb-config-client-logs
          mountPath: /configs/orientdb-client-log.properties
          subPath: orientdb-client-log.properties
        - name: orientdb-config-server-logs
          mountPath: /configs/orientdb-server-log.properties
          subPath: orientdb-server-log.properties
        - name: orientdb-config-plugin
          mountPath: /configs/pom.xml
          subPath: pom.xml
        - name: orientdb-databases
          mountPath: /orientdb/databases
        - name: orientdb-backup
          mountPath: /orientdb/backup
        - name: orientdb-data
          mountPath: /orientdb/bin/data
      volumes:
      - name: config
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: orientdb-config-backups
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-backups
      - name: orientdb-config-events
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-events
      - name: orientdb-config-distributed
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-distributed
      - name: orientdb-config-hazelcast
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-hazelcast
      - name: orientdb-config-server
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-server
      - name: orientdb-config-client-logs
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-client-logs
      - name: orientdb-config-server-logs
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-server-logs
      - name: orientdb-config-plugin
        configMap:
          name: orientdb-configmap-plugin
      - name: orientdb-data
        hostPath:
          path: /import_data
          type: Directory
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: orientdb-databases
      labels:
        service: orientdb
        type: pv-claim
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
  - metadata:
      name: orientdb-backup
      labels:
        service: orientdb
        type: pv-claim
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

Headkess service looks like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: orientdbservice
  labels:
    service: orientdb
    type: headless-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    service: orientdb
    type: container-deployment
  ports:
  - port: 2424
    name: port-binary
  - port: 2480
    name: port-http
  - name: hazelcast
    port: 5701
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Hazelcast members to discover themselves, you also need to:

- specify `containerPort` for Hazelcast (port `5701`)
- create a Kubernetes Service for Hazelcast (port `5701`, in case of using DNS Lookup Discovery, the service needs to be `type: ClusterIP` and `clusterIP: None`)

You can find more information about the configuration in the following sources:

- [Official README](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes) ([DNS Lookup section](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes#dns-lookup))
- [Code Sample using DNS Lookup](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes/samples/springboot-k8s-hello-world)
- [General Hazelcast Code Sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/kubernetes)

Comment: I have added updates with the port defined for hazelcast in both stateful set and headless service. However, it did not solve the problem. The nodes still do not find each other